# Find all function calls by a function

Tags: python, function, inspect, code-inspection

What is the best way to find all function calls that a function makes? I want to do this at runtime (likely with a decorator).

Is the best way to retrieve the source code with `inspect` (this means that I will have to have access to the source code...so no interactive interpreter support) and then parse it with `ast`? Is there a better way?

Python 2.7 preferred, but not required. I'd like it to be simple enough to do myself. If others have done it, I would look at the source code so I could figure it out.

Ultimately, I will only be interested in calls to functions with a particular decorator, but there are already answers to that part on SO.

Edit:

```
def f():
    return g(1)


@Interesting
def g(x):
    return x + 1

print what_interesting_functions_does_this_call(f)
```

prints

```
(<function g at 0x7f2a1ec72a28>,)
```

I realize now that because of how dynamic Python is, this is not possible in the general case. But could I cover some subset of cases?

FYI: "You are an idiot and why would you ever think to be able to tell what functions are called by another function and I can't think of any reason why this would ever be useful, therefore it must not be useful for you" is an okay response. I would like to know.

Comment: can you add an example with a function and the expected output? do you want to count how many times it calls each function?

Comment: define function calls? are you including builtins? or just your funcions?

Comment: Just my functions. I will annotate them if they are 'interesting'.

Comment: You may also consider `import profile` and then `runcall(your_function)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> def a():
...    float("1.2")
...    int("1")
...    b()
...
>>> def b():
...    sum([1,2,3])
...
>>> a()
>>> import dis
>>> dis
<module 'dis' from 'C:\Python26\lib\dis.pyc'>
>>> dis.dis(a)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (float)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 ('1.2')
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              9 POP_TOP

  3          10 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (int)
             13 LOAD_CONST               2 ('1')
             16 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             19 POP_TOP

  4          20 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (b)
             23 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             26 POP_TOP
             27 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             30 RETURN_VALUE
>>>
```

you could just count the "CALL_FUNCTION"  ...

in general I dont think you want to do something like this in production code ...