# get all functions called in a function or source code

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaprogramming

Originally I thought I'd have to parse out the source code of a function to get all the functions it was calling, but even if I did that I'd only have the names of the functions, not the functions themselves.

Then I found a few questions similar to mine, for example:
[Find all function calls by a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16042005/find-all-function-calls-by-a-function)

However all the other answers provide solutions that return a list of function names, they do not return the actual functions themselves. I would like to get a list of functions called in a function, or source code as a list of actual functions is that possible? should I use an `ast` solution but convert the `ast` FunctionDef object to a function object somehow? or can this be done with `dis`? Here's what I have so far:

```
import dis
def list_func_calls(fn):
    funcs = []
    bytecode = dis.Bytecode(fn)
    instrs = list(reversed([instr for instr in bytecode]))
    for (ix, instr) in enumerate(instrs):
        if instr.opname == "CALL_FUNCTION":
            load_func_instr = instrs[ix + instr.arg + 1]
            funcs.append(load_func_instr.argval)

    return ["%d. %s" % (ix, funcname) for (ix, funcname) in enumerate(reversed(funcs), 1)]

def a():
    print(b())

def b():
    return 'hi'

list_func_calls(a)
```

I can imagine getting the called function from the Bytecode might be difficult, but I don't really know, I'm way out of my league with this one, but I'd like to get back:

```
[<function print>, <function __main__.b()>]
```

Is this sort of thing even possible?

Comment: The name of the function being called is *all that the bytecode actually contains*.  That name gets looked up at runtime; you can do the same, with something like `globals()[name]` (assuming that the function being analyzed is in the same module as your code).  Also: your code will only successfully find the name of the function being called in particularly simple situations.  If any of the parameters to the function were expressions, rather than simply variables or literals (and therefore require more than one bytecode operation to push on the stack), you'll be looking in the wrong place.

Comment: @jasonharper thanks, knowing this gives me much better intuition now. every function has a `__globals__` attribute, can I use that to consistently get the function of `[name]`?

Comment: Yes, `__globals__` should work for the cases where the called function is referenced by a global name.  You'll still have troubles with nested functions, lambdas, methods, etc., that have no global name.

Comment: @jasonharper is there any kind of solution for those? besides the brute force parsing approach, of course...

Comment: You could handle additional cases with additional work, but this is ultimately not a solvable problem - there is too much room for runtime variability in what function gets called.  Even in simple cases of calling a global function by name - that name could be reassigned between the time you analyzed the calling function, and the time the function was actually called.  Or consider `random.choice(myListOfFunctions)()` - what would you want your code to return in that case?